# Unable to delete space in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` inside a `LinearLayout` of a `ListView` item. Its a simple layout. When a `TextView` is pressed , I hide the `TextView` and show the `EditText` component . `EditText` gets text set to it inside the `getView` function of a custom array adapter class.

But suddenly I am not able to delete any space in the `EditText` component . It was working fine . I really couldn't understand what caused it.

All I do a little extra to show the keypad is

```
final EditText reminderTextEditorObject = (EditText) ((View) reminderItem).findViewById(R.id.reminderTextEditor);
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              keyboard.showSoftInput(reminderTextEditorObject, 0);
          }
      }, 1);
      reminderTextEditorObject.requestFocus();
      reminderTextEditorObject.setSelection(reminderTextEditorObject.getText().length());
```

I guess that this is something that is caused by some keyhandling stuff . But not able to figure a solution . Please help as this is a vital part of my app

Comment: Try printing the reminderTextEditorObject.getText().length() and see what it does...

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Maybe upload a screenshot?

Comment: @San -  I checked the length of the text inside editor object . It gives out perfect .

Comment: @AndyFaizan - screenshot is not going to be of a great use . It's just not deleting anything. If I long press it, then it deletes all words except the first one . 
I checked this link . He too has faced similar issue, but in gallery
[almost similar issue link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976384/soft-keyboard-del-key-fails-in-edittext-on-gallery-widget)

Comment: Well anyhow, I changed my design . I went for an alertdialog to edit the text .Thanks guys

Comment: I know it is a 2 year-old thread but I'm facing a similar problem and couldn't find a solution. Does anyone have some news about this issue?